# using compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version" give Error

Tags: android, kotlin

In this gradle its throwing error:

> Error:(57, 0) Could not get unknown property 'anko_version' for object
>   of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   Open File

Can any one help me?

Comment: Share the scenario when you are facing this issue.

Comment: Have you added this ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4' in projects build.gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an undefined property `anko_version` in your gradle file.

Just add following line to your build.gradle(:project)

```
ext.anko_version = '0.10.0'
```

Like:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ...
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.0'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked after updating Android Studio 3.2.1, Gradle, and Kotlin

for Build.Gradle (Project MyFirstApp)

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
//ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
```

for Build.Gradle (Module app) dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
//implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
//implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin:stdlib-jre"
```

Helpful Article:
https://hubpages.com/technology/How-to-build-an-Android-App